# Servlet how to call mutiple submit button

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, servlets

I have a problem regarding my simple application I have 2 separate .JSP file let say register and login.jsp both have submit action and both this jsp share the same servlet let say usercontrol.servlet how can I call the action once the login button is clicked the same also with register.jsp if they sharecommon servlet?

here is my servlet code:

```
if(request.getParameter("register").equals("Register")){
            if(request.getParameter("first") == "" || request.getParameter("middle") == "" || request.getParameter("last") == "" || 
                    request.getParameter("loginid") == "" || request.getParameter("pass") == "" || request.getParameter("pass2")== ""){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot leave null value from one of the textfields");
                response.sendRedirect("AdminPage/Register.jsp");

            }
            //else if(request.getParameter("pass") != request.getParameter("pass2")){
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password Mismatch, Check you password and retype it correctly");
                //response.sendRedirect("AdminPage/Register.jsp");
            //}
            else{
                RegisterUser(request, response);
            }
    }

    else if(request.getParameter("login").equals("Login")){
        if(request.getParameter("username") == ""){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username is required");
            response.sendRedirect("AdminPage/Login.jsp");
        }
        else if(request.getParameter("password") == ""){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password is required");
            response.sendRedirect("AdminPage/Login.jsp");
        }
        else if(request.getParameter("username") == "" || request.getParameter("password") == ""){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password/Username is required");
            response.sendRedirect("AdminPage/Login.jsp");
        }
        else{
            LoginUser(response, request);
        }   
    }
```

I'm integrating my application with hibernate.

this are my jsp submit buttons I did not include the whole forms I just include the submit button.

Login.jsp

```
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
```

Register.jsp

```
<input type="submit" name="register" value="Register"/>
```

My question is everytime I run the application it always does all the action in the if..else statement is there any other ways to fix this?

Comment: **My WORD!!!!** Including a `JOptionPane` inside a Web Application is **fully discouraged**. That's why I suggest not following all examples on [RoseIndia.net](http://www.roseindia.net).

Comment: How are you putting the values Register and Login in the request ?Seems like both are available in the request. Can you post your jsp?

Comment: well actually this is just a testing code of course i will not implement JOptionpane on my application I just want to know if the if...else statement is calling the right method..sorry for the JOptionpane.

Comment: Thats what loggers are for - we _have_ the technology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your jsp you should have submit button as

for login.jsp

```
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"/>
```

for register.jsp

```
<input type="submit" name="register" value="Register"/>
```

Now in servlet you can check like

```
if(request.getParameter("login") != null) {
  // request is comming from login jsp
  // do validation, perform actual transaction 
} else if(request.getParameter("register") != null) {
  // request is comming from register jsp
  // do validation, perform actual transaction 
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot its working now sometimes I don't unserstand java sometimes it easy to understand, I mean null and "" is different in java by the way what is the datatype of the request.getParameter, it object or string?

Comment: do you know koushik? i'm his son :) just kidding